# Selection of all post ids in wordpress to customise in css

Tags: wordpress, post

I want to target all posts to alter some common elements in css.

I am currently having to define the following for each post created:

```
.postid-65 #content {
    display: none;  
}

.postid-68 #content {
    display: none;  
}
```

What I want is for all post that are created to have the `#content` display as `none`. If I need to use PHP, my skills are very limited; so could you please explain what I would have to do?

Comment: In most themes, the content is wrapped in an additional div that has post/page classes. It's hard to know without seeing your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the HTML source of your pages, you'll find that what you're trying to blank out will be wrapped with <div> tags. Inside the div will be a class declaration. Something like <div class = "entry-content"> . The class can be selected with the CSS class selector, "." . So in my example, taken from the 2012 theme, the CSS would be:

```
.entry-content {display:none;}
```

Note this is probably a very inelegant way of doing whatever you're trying to achieve. You're content is still being generated and sent to the client's browser, will still be seen by many browser configurations, and indexed by search engines.